# pass field value to a function .extra()

Tags: django

After trying for hours, I am coming here. I have the following model:

```
class Items(models.Model):
     date=models.DateField()
     giver=models.IntegerField()


Class Givers(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Basically, an item could be given by donators from Givers model or it could be bought by user. If given, giver field stores id from Givers model. Else, it is 0. Now I want a query that will list out my items. If giver>0, I need to show the name of the giver. I can't create relationships here. This query has brought me so close and works like a charm on literal values but I want to provide the 'giver' field instead:

```
   data=Items.objects.all().extra(select={'giver_name':giver_name(1,False)}).values('giver_name','id','date')
```

It works like a charm even if given any number (exists or not exists). But I want to do something like this but it fails cos field is not found or undefined:

```
   data=Items.objects.all().extra(select={'giver_name':giver_name(giver,False)}).values('giver_name','id','date')
```

giver_name is a function that accepts id of a giver and a boolean value and returns a name.

Comment: This can't possibly work; you're mixing up two levels of code (the query in the database, and the Python code in Django). `giver_name()` would need to be called on every row as part of the query, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How do you think I can achieve it? Any idea please.